# C# Write A Clipboard Monitor: Why Must Override WndProc in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Recently I am working on writing a global clipboard monitor. The API used is [AddClipboardFormatListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649033(VS.85).aspx). One of the example can be found in [Clipboard Listener on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148400/clipboard-monitor).

Apart from using AddClipboardFormatListener API, the important step is add following code into the form I want to use.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  switch (m.Msg)
  {
    case ClipboardContentCaptureHelper.WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
      IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
      string data;
      if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
      {
        data = (string)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        // logging code are ignored here
      }
      break;

    default:
      base.WndProc(ref m);
      break;
  }
}
```

My question is since AddClipboardListener accept a Handle(IntPtr) as the parameter pointed to the function/method which is going to be served as a customized listener, why my attempt of declare a delegate type and make an instance, then use [Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at4fb09f(v=vs.110).aspx) method to convert it to IntPtr, pass to AddClipboardListener, will not work?

Are there any performance concerns when I override [WndProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx) method? Because I think it will intercept all the messages in Windows.

Comment: I have already got a working demo by overriding. But I want to know are there any ways to avoid using WndProc, since it is to powerful and global.

Comment: WndProc is not global, it is per-window.

Comment: And AddClipboardListener make it globally hear the clipboard update message? So are there any ways to write another method/function to avoid override WndProc? My attempt to add a instance delegate and method was failed.

Comment: Every window already runs its own WndProc, you are just overriding the default one so that it processes WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE instead of ignoring it.

Comment: Your Window already processes those messages, overriding WndProc, you are allowed to partake. If you are receiving Clipboard events, that Window has also registered [AddClipboardFormatListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649033(v=vs.85).aspx). Don't forget to set the Result: `m.Result = (IntPtr)0;` when you process `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`.

Comment: It is just how the api works.  You must pass the handle of a window to AddClipboardFormatListener().  When it has something interesting to tell then it sends the WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message to that window.  To get that message in a Winforms app you must override WndProc().  It is the basic way Windows has worked for the past 30 years.  Modern api additions are friendlier, like WinRT, which has a lot more of a .NET look-and-feel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AddClipboardFormatListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649033.aspx) expects a handle to a native window as the argument. An `HWND` maps to an `IntPtr` in C#. That doesn't mean that you can pass any other type that can be converted to an `IntPtr` as the argument. The API needs a window, so that it can send messages to its window procedure. That's how this API (and many others) implements its notification system.

There are no immediate performance issues with overriding the window procedure. Every native application does essentially the same. The frequency at which messages arrive is fairly low, too. Ignoring pathological designs, it should never hit or stay above 100/s.